# Zend PDF DrawLine Printout Issue

Tags: pdf, zend-framework, line, draw

Will try to explain as best as possible.

So I've created a PDF using Zend PDF, it uses DrawLine which works perfectly fine when i open the PDF but when i send it to the printer straight from the browser the lines don't display. If i save the PDF to my documents first and print it that way the lines display fine.. Have attached photos to show:

Printed from browser:
[image: printed from browser]

Printed from my documents:
[image: printed from my documents]

Has anyone had this problem before, or know of this issue? 
Many thanks,

Comment: Any chance to get access to this file? And what browser/pdf viewer you'd used?

Comment: Turns out the problem definitley was a browser issue. It's not a file that can be fully shared i'm afraid, but thanks for offering to help :)

Comment: In that case you should open a bug report at the browser/reader vendor.

Answer (score 0):

It was a browser issue.. Problem solved in IE